# Data is not retrieving by g:select in Grails 3

Tags: grails, groovy

Data is not retrieving by g:select in Grails 3.
My code is like below-

```
<g:select from="${Machine_summaryList}" name="brand" />
```

Here "Machine_summaryList" is List of "Machine_summary" class and "brand" is the column which data I need to retrieve.

Comment: and the problem is?

Comment: Here all brand name should come in select but Data is not retrieving

Comment: how do you know? mayby your list is empty?

Comment: I have data in list.

Comment: try adding `optionKey` and `value` attributes as per http://docs.grails.org/3.1.0/ref/Tags/select.html

Comment: I have also used this
<g:select from="${Machine_summaryList}" name="brand" value="${it?.sl_no}" optionKey="sl_no" />
but not working

Comment: see if you have something in html for this select

Comment: I'm using this on GSP page

Comment: this is what I mean: click "show page source code" in your browser

Comment: This is HTML <select name="brand" id="brand"></select>

Comment: so, your list `Machine_summaryList` is obviously empty

Comment: No. Its not empty. Data is showing in list.gsp by calling **"Machine_summaryList"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this procedure works for me

```
<g:select from="${project.Machine_summary.executeQuery("select distinct c.brand from Machine_summary c")}" name="brand" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `optionValue="brand"` in this case.

Your `g:select` must be like:

```
<g:select from="${Machine_summaryList}" name="brand" optionKey="id" optionValue="brand"/>
```

When the form will submit, you will receive the selected Machine in `params.brand`.

Comment: I also used this one but its not working whereas I have data in Machine_summaryList and it throws data in List.gsp by using "${Machine_summaryList}" but its not working on g:select